# Cannot express a ref-like struct with other ref-like struct members [<IsByRefLike; Struct>]

Tags: struct, f#, byref

I am experimenting with a non-allocating path segment enumerator using nested `IsByRefLike` struct types, but the compiler is putting up a wall of "*A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.*". Is that the end of the road for the experiment, or is the intent possible to express?

```
namespace Experiment

open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<IsByRefLike; Struct>]
type refoption<'T> =
    | RefNone
    | RefSome of value: 'T

[<IsByRefLike; Struct; RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type FilePathStepRef =
    | Drive of driveName: ReadOnlySpan<char>
    | Parent of parentName: ReadOnlySpan<char>
    | Name of name: ReadOnlySpan<char>

[<IsByRefLike; Struct>]
type FilePathStepRefEnumerator =
    internal
        { Initial: ReadOnlySpan<char>
          mutable Head: FilePathStepRef refoption // Compiler error
          mutable Tail: ReadOnlySpan<char> }

    // The remaining code is not necessary to exhibit the error.

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() =
            this.Head <- RefNone
            this.Tail <- ReadOnlySpan.Empty

    member this.Current: FilePathStepRef refoption = this.Head

    member this.MoveNext() =
        if this.Tail.Length = 0 then
            false
        else
            // TODO
            true

    member this.GetEnumerator() = this
```

Since all types involves appear to be `IsByRefLike`, my assumption was that it would work.

Perhaps the `refoption` type is missing a constraint on `'T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, at least, you can't use a ref-like struct as a generic parameter: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65112

Looks like this will be possible in .NET 8

Comment: Well that was short, to the point and informative.